How to align margin to allow enough space in grid using wpf ui?
I want to minimize the space between the grid and rectangle on my application, the problem there is big space them want to adjust the margins of the grid to fit below the rectangle so can have a good ui for my wpf application.
<UserControl x:Class="Feedmill_Weighbridge.Presentation.UCPremixBatch"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Feedmill_Weighbridge.Presentation"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="680" d:DesignWidth="800">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="StockCode" Source="{Binding Code}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="StockDescription" Source="{Binding Description}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,35,-966,3.6" Width="1766">
    <Label Content="Premix Batch Material Management" BorderThickness="1.5" BorderBrush="#FF0B0B0B" Background="#FF383838" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="275" Stroke="#FFCFCFD1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" Margin="14,104,0,0"/>
    <Label Content="Recipe Details" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE" Background="#FFE3E3E3" BorderThickness="1.5" Foreground="Black" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Margin="14,103,0,0"/>
    <!-- IDX -->
    <Label x:Name="lblIDX" FontSize="10" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Visible" Content="IDX:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE3E3E3" Margin="17,140,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtIDX" FontSize="10" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible" Height="26" Margin="146,137,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    <!-- Recipe -->
    <Label x:Name="lblActive_Copy1" FontSize="10" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Visible" Content="Recipe:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE3E3E3" Margin="17,168,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtRecipe" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible" Height="26" Margin="146,165,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    <!-- Rec No -->
    <Label x:Name="lblRecNo" FontSize="10" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Visible" Content="Rec No:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE3E3E3" Margin="17,196,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtRecNo" FontSize="10" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible" Height="26" Margin="146,193,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    <!-- Description -->
    <Label x:Name="lblActive_Copy2" FontSize="10" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Visible" Content="Description:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE3E3E3" Margin="17,224,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtDescription" FontSize="10" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible" Height="26" Margin="146,221,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    <!-- Batch Size -->
    <Label x:Name="lblActive_Copy3" FontSize="10" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Visible" Content="Batch Size:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE3E3E3" Margin="17,252,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtBatchSize" FontSize="10" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible" Height="26" Margin="146,249,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    <!-- Feed First Recipe Name -->
    <Label x:Name="lblActive_Copy5" FontSize="10" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Visible" Content="Feed First Recipe Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE3E3E3" Margin="17,280,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtFeedFirstName" FontSize="10" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible" Height="26" Margin="146,277,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    <!-- Bag Weight -->
    <Label x:Name="lblBagWeight" FontSize="10" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Visible" Content="Bag Weight:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE3E3E3" Margin="17,308,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtBagWeight" FontSize="10" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible" Height="26" Margin="146,305,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    <!-- Save Button -->
    <Button x:Name="btnAdd_Copy" Content="Save" Click="btnAdd_Click" Background="ForestGreen" BorderBrush="ForestGreen" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="146,340,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" />

    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="275" Stroke="#FFCFCFD1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="270" Margin="288,103,0,0"/>
    <Label Content="Ingredient Totals" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="270" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE" Background="#FFE3E3E3" BorderThickness="1.5" Foreground="Black" Height="29" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Margin="288,104,0,0"/>

    <Label x:Name="lblActive_Copy7" FontSize="10" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Visible" Content="Macros:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE3E3E3" Margin="296,140,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE" Height="23"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtMacroTotal" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible" Height="23" Margin="426,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="122"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblActive_Copy8" FontSize="10" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Visible" Content="Total:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE3E3E3" Margin="295,168,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE" Height="23"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtTotal" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible" Height="23" Margin="426,168,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="122"/>
    <Label Content="Macros" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="780" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE" Background="#FFE3E3E3" BorderThickness="1.5" Foreground="Black" Height="35" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Margin="14,460,0,0"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblDriverName_Copy" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Visible" Content="Recipe Code:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="#FFE3E3E3" Margin="17,65,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFBEBEBE"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbxRecipe" TabIndex="1" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="207,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214" SelectionChanged="cbxRecipe_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ComboBox>

    <DataGrid x:Name="dgvMacroRecipe" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectedCellsChanged="dgvMacroRecipe_SelectedCellsChanged" CellEditEnding="dgvMacroRecipe_CellEditEnding"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFBBBBBB" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" FontWeight="Normal" BorderBrush="#FF767676" Margin="14,496,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="12" Width="780"  >
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="14"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF383838"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="SeparatorVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Visibility="Visible" Width="5">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding idx}" Header="IDX" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Hidden">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding idx1}" Header="IDX" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Visibility="Visible" Width="5">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RM_Code}" Header="RM Code" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="8">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Visibility="Visible" Width="5">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Stock Code">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtStockCode"  Text="{Binding [Stock Code]}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Height="22" Width="auto" x:Name="cbxMacroStockType" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StockCode}}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedValue="Code" SelectedValuePath="idx1" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"   DropDownClosed="cbxMacroStockType_DropDownClosed" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Visibility="Visible" Width="5">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding [Stock Description]}" Header="Stock Description" Width="auto" IsReadOnly="True" FontWeight="SemiBold">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="Yes">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="No">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF6969"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Visibility="Visible" Width="5">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Percentage}" Header="Percentage" Width="auto" FontWeight="SemiBold">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="Yes">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="No">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF6969"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Visibility="Visible" Width="5">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Kilograms}" Header="Kilograms" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" FontWeight="SemiBold">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Visibility="Visible" Width="5">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    
    <!-- Grid for No. OF PREMIX PACKS MADE -->
    <Grid Margin="14,600,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="NO OF PREMIX PACKS MADE:" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBox Width="80" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>


</Grid>


`

Don't lay out elements by margins. Use StackPanel or other Panels.

Please post a screenshot of the result

WPF docs: How to: Position the Child Elements of a Grid, Tutorial: Use Grid and StackPanel to create a simple weather app
